# Django Почему не срабатывает проверка формы

Tags: django

Собственно вопрос вот в чем, почему не срабатывает проверка, логика такая что пользователь добавляет название и ссылку а программа "дает" ссылке название и нужно проверить чтоб названия не повторялись с тем что уже есть. По сути  происходит  что форма не валидна. И можно сказать что проверка проходит но тогда нужно вернуть станицу со всеми данными и ошибку, а я только нашел как вернуть шаблон страницы или же перенаправить на нее саму же. Форма становится не валидная когда я добавляю unique=True в модель, а то что происходит в def title_valid(self) вообще ни чего. Помогите пожалуйста

```
 class LinkPage(ListView):
    model = Link
    template_name = 'links/links.html'
    context_object_name = 'links'
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(LinkPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['form'] = LinkAddForm
        ctx['allmylinks'] = list(Link.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))

        return ctx

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = request.POST.copy()
        post['user'] = request.user
        request.POST = post
        context = LinkAddForm(request.POST)
        if context.is_valid():
            context.save()
            return redirect('linkpage')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(u'ОШИБОЧКА')
```

```
    class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
    class LinkAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Название cсылки')
    link = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Ссылка')


    def title_valid(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if data == Link.objects.get('title'):
            print('shit')
            raise ValidationError('Такое название уже существует')
        else:
            return data


    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['title', 'link', 'user']
        widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

```
{% block main-section %}
    <h1>Создание ссылок</h1>
    <form class="container" method="POST">
        <h3>Комментарии</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
    
    <h1>Доступные ссылки</h1>
{% for link in allmylinks %}
    <div>
    ССЫЛКА - <a href="{{ link.link }}">/link/{{ link.title }}/</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Link.objects.get('title') - что Вы хотите этим получить?

Comment: Взять все title которые уже созданы и есть в базе. Пробовал также Link.objects[‘title’]. Проверка есть ли такое название уже

Comment: Это не так делается. нужно использовать "filter" и "exists"

Comment: Михаил, можно пример как должно быть, потому что по такой же схеме как здесь, у меня когда я отслеживал slug поле в другом проекте все сработало, проверка прошла

Comment: def title_valid(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if data == Link.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Такое название уже существует')
        else:
            return data. Если так то тоже не работает

Comment: Допинал, нужно было вывести         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('linkpage')
        else:
            form = LinkAddForm(request.POST)
            allmylinks = list(Link.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
            context = {'form': form,
                        'allmylinks' : allmylinks,
                       }
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)